# Subclass of MPMoviePlayerViewController doesn't dismiss animated - Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've subclassed `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, and method `[parentViewController dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated]` doesn't dismiss it animated. Player just disappears. Even without dismissing it manually and just press "Done" button - player disappears without animation. Inside subclassed player I add button to my player view, that's it. Where could be the problem? Here is some code of initialization my player.

```
MyMovieViewController *playerView = [[[MyMovieViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url] autorelease];
[playerView setSelectedVideo:video];
[playerView.moviePlayer setAllowsAirPlay:YES];
[playerView.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[[MenuController sharedInstance].menuView setHidden:YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playBackChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:playerView.moviePlayer];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:playerView.moviePlayer];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playBackChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:playerView.moviePlayer];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerView];
```

Comment: Are you calling that method on the instance of your `MPMoviePlayerViewController` subclass or on its parent viewController? The latter would be correct.

Comment: @Till I call it from parent viewController

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on when and where did you call the dismiss method. Make sure it looks like this:

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];`

Comment: When using MPMoviePlayerViewController, you are supposed to use [`dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/UIViewController_MediaPlayer_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated) instead.

Comment: Doesn't help :( I changed MyMovieViewController to MPMoviePlayerViewController and it was animated without any dismiss methods. I just tap done button and player dismisses animated.